# Expected variables not defined when using node inspect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I'm trying to familiarize myself with debugging using the `node inspect` command. I've written as simple script `use_debugger.js` which defines a function and calls it:

```
function count(nums, maxes) {
  debugger;
  return maxes;
}

count([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]);
```

When I drop into the debugger, I would expect `nums` to be defined and have the value `[1, 2, 3]`. However, if I run `node inspect use_debugger.js` and then type `c` and `nums` in the REPL, I get that it is not defined:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:Scratch kurtpeek$ node --inspect-brk use_debugger.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/7adfaada-c939-44a3-9150-6d1326b8c7d0
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
^C
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:Scratch kurtpeek$ node inspect use_debugger.js
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/54fb6a12-82c8-4454-8307-6d120b0c26e8
< For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in use_debugger.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function count(nums, maxes) {
  2   debugger;
  3   return maxes;
debug> c
break in use_debugger.js:2
  1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function count(nums, maxes) {
> 2   debugger;
  3   return maxes;
  4 }
debug> maxes
repl:1
maxes
^

ReferenceError: maxes is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:101:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:279:6)
    at REPLServer.controlEval (internal/deps/node-inspect/lib/internal/inspect_repl.js:521:25)
    at bound (domain.js:396:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:409:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:621:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:290:10)
debug>
```

Should I not be able to 'access' the variables in the function's scope, `nums` and `maxes`?

**Update**

To further document [estus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus) answer, the `exec maxes` command worked for me:

```
debug> exec maxes
[ 4, 5 ]
```

As stated in https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_information, the `exec expr` command executes an expression in the debugging script's context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
maxes
```

evaluates `maxes` in REPL scope, not `count` function scope.

As explained in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_information):

> repl - Open debugger's repl for evaluation in debugging script's context
>
> exec expr - Execute an expression in debugging script's context

To evaluate `maxes` in debugging scope, it should be either:

```
repl
maxes
```

Or:

```
exec maxes
```

Comment: While debugging, `eval` doesn't evaluate the code in debugging script's context.

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Thanks for noticing, that's a typo, it's `exec`.